# Redux randomly resets a reducer's state

Tags: redux, react-redux, state

I've run into a problem and I need a hand.

This is more of a theoretical approach rather than practical.

My problem is:
I am making an app in my spare time, which is rather complex - it's supposed to resemble a social network of sorts to an extent.

I have 10 reducers in my `combineReducers` function and a crapload of actions fire up when a user either goes to their dashboard or the start/home page - to fetch the user's uploaded images, videos, their profile picture, posts of their friends, posts directed to them, all of their posts together regardless of whether they are images, videos, audio posts or textual and groups they're a part of.

However, some of the reducers affect others, and simply reset them, but they were supposed to act independently of one another.
In the images below, you can clearly see that some textual posts were loaded in one of the dispatched actions, only to be completely reset by another action from a completely different reducer with a different type constant when loading videos.

In case it matters, some of my separate reducer objects share the property `loading`, initially set to `null` or `false`.

The maintainer on GitHub might have also been stumped, as they recommended that I ask my question here.

[The reducer loads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mm3B6.png)

[Different reducer randomly resets another one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6XfO.png)

Comment: Without sharing actually any code, it's almost impossible to help you. If I were to guess, I'd say that your reducer is missing a `default` case doing a `return state` or returns something different than the original state passed in.
Remember that **every reducer will always be called with all actions**.

Comment: In addition to what @phry said about default cases, make sure that the string names for each action type are unique for every reducer.  If you have actions with the same names then multiple reducers will respond to them.  It is common to prefix the action names to avoid naming collisions, like `"media/GET_ALL_MY_MEDIA"`

Comment: I've found the problem. I was returning `initialState` in my `default` case in `switch`. Changed it to `state` (which was my current state) and have fixed the problem. I thought that this was some theoretical bug with redux, but it was my dumb bum. Thank you both for pushing me in the right direction, as that was all I needed :)

Comment: I know it's to late, considering date on post, but i encountered similar issue. For me solution was that in every case of the switch, which how i structure reducers, use `state.propertyX` to all other properties present in reducer, except that one which is case. Why, or how, they triggered each other in this particular reducer, but no similar thing is happened in other reducers, i'm not sure...